# result metrics for non gui mode execution in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Is there any way to collection all metrics (summary, aggregation, synthesis, error messages etc.) in a single csv file for non gui mode execution.

or get all details in database. I tried with backend listener but it did not provide all details.

Answer (score 0):

All the metrics are in the [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles).

Aggregate, Summary, Synthesis, etc. are **calculated** from the values in the .jtl file.

You can use [JMeter Plugins Command Line Tool](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeterpluginscmd) to generate them from the .jtl results file and then if you want to have all of them in a single file you can use your operating system mechanisms for combining several CSV files into a single one like:

- Windows: use [copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/copy) command

  ```
   copy first.csv + second.csv result.csv
  ```
- Unix and derivatives: use [cat](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cat.1.html) command

  ```
   cat first.csv second.csv result.csv
  ```

Comment: yes that we can do. but our requirement is to read file continuously and fetch data on every one minute during execution. This will require efforts to read and parse information multiple times as per requirement. can we do this activity using java code directly for summary, aggregate result, synthesis listeners and get a single file?